# .htaccess - Remove ALL parameters from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to remove all `GET` parameters from address, I tried somethink like this:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /index.php?url=$1&ip=$2&category=$3 [NC]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working...

I need to redirect from:

```
http://example.com/folder/index.php?url=google.com&ip=10.0.0.0&category=website
```

to

```
http://example.com/folder
```

But keep data from parameters - I need to get it by `$_GET['parameter']`.

Comment: Using GET method it is not possible to hide the parameters.

Comment: Why do you want to use GET anyways its insecure.

Comment: The `$_GET` array is not populated if the query string is not present. The only way you can have them not appear in the address bar, but available to `$_POST`, is by using exactly that: the `POST` method.

Answer (score 3):

You could map `http://example.com/folder` onto `http://example.com/folder/index.php?url=google.com&ip=10.0.0.0&category=website`, but then you couldn't pass different query string parameters.

If you want to pass data through the URL then the data *has to appear in the URL*.